# Generate a random tree population

Tags: trees, randomized-algorithms, genetic-algorithms

Given

- a unbalanced k-ary tree `base` (with internal nodes that represent operators and leafs representing values) from the space of all unbalanced k-ary trees `T`
- a distance function `delta(t, t') = number of edit operations to transform t into t'`
- the edit operations `add(t)` (adding a random leaf), `remove(t)` (removing a random subtree), `relabel(t)` (relabel a random node) `merge(t, t')` (merge `t` and `t'`)

> For a genetic algorithm I need to generate a population of `n` trees that are not more than `k` edit operations away from `base`. I must prove that any tree within this space has equal propablity to be generated and that any tree can be generated.

The only idea I can think of was:

1. draw a random number `l` within `[0, k]`
2. define a random sequence `seq` of size `l` edit operations
3. apply `seq` to `base`

This aproach though does not garanty that any tree less than k away from base is generated?!

//EDIT

My other approach:

1. Generate a random tree `rt`
2. Measure distance `d` and calculate `seq` the optimal set of edit operations beween `rt` and `base`
3. apply `[k-d, d]` edit operations to `rt`

I am not shure if in that way any tree can be generated with the same propability.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  It suffices to ask how to generate a single tree with the right distribution.  If you can do that, you can repeat the procedure $n$ times.  However, sampling with exactly that distribution looks like it might be challenging.  Your methods don't yield a uniform distribution on trees.  I imagine you could read about MCMC methods, but I don't know if they'll be applicable here.  Would you be OK with a sampler that has approximately the right distribution, even if it's not exactly right?  (Still seems like a hard problem.)